# Pandas df.to_excel is way to slow, is there anyway to speed it up?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I'm working with a set of data which has almost 60 columns (Text/Address/Numbers). After processing the data using [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/), I have to export it to `xlsx` format.

This is how I'm generating the output:

```py
with pd.ExcelWriter("output.xlsx", engine='xlsxwriter') as writer:
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="sheet", index=False)
```

I have also tried this method:

```py
df.to_excel('output.xlsx', index=False, engine='xlsxwriter')
```

What I have noticed is, generating `xlsx` is remarkably slower than a format like `csv`. And as the number of records grows, the time of generating the `xlsx` file significantly increases.

[image]

Is this the normal and expected behavior of `.to_excel` or there is something wrong here? is there any way to debug and solve this problem?

---

I have to be able to generate `xlsx` files for ~300K to ~600K records in matter of seconds, but as you can see it takes me around 6 minutes to generate an excel file for about 500K records.

The hardware that I'm using to generate these files has 16 Core of CPU, and 64 GB of memory.

Comment: I don't think you'll get comparable speeds, but the time diff is interesting.

Comment: What is wrong about exporting to csv and afterwards importing csv in excel?

Comment: @svebert For now, that's what we are doing. However, as the data contains a lot of different kind of characters, (just to name some: semi-colon, colon, comma, single and double quotation, etc) Its really hard to get a clean and working CVS output out of it. Not to mention that some of this characters are meaningful and we can't just get rid of them.

Comment: When you say “I  have to be able to generate xlsx files for ~300K to ~600K records in matter of seconds“ how are you doing that?

Comment: @Ravexina but you use df.to_csv() at the moment? Or something else?

Comment: @jmcnamara I have to, but obviously I'm to able to do it.  Right now we are using csv but it comes with it's own [challenges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73319597/pandas-df-to-excel-is-way-to-slow-is-there-anyway-to-speed-it-up#comment129483528_73319597).

Comment: @svebert Yeah, we're using `df.to_csv()`.

Comment: you wish to write the output to same sheet in a single xlsx file or multiple xlsx files would work?

Answer (score 2):

I found a slightly faster solution, than just using `engine='xlsxwriter'`

```py
import pandas as pd
from xlsxwriter.workbook import Workbook

def export_excel(df: pd.DataFrame, file_path_out: str):
    workbook = Workbook(file_path_out)
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

    worksheet.write_row(0, 0, [col for col in df.columns])

    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        worksheet.write_row(index+1, 0, [col for col in row])
    workbook.close()
```

The following table shows the runtime for three methods for 100 to 50k rows of random data (with 60 cols). The measured time is in seconds. openpyxl and xlsxwriter are df.export_excel(engine=...) calls and export_excel is my proposed code, above. Its not a game changer... but its faster

```
row count: openpyxl, xlsxwriter, export_excel
100: 0.1272597312927246, 0.15707993507385254, 0.12616825103759766
1000: 1.1917698383331299, 0.8460557460784912, 0.7760021686553955
10000: 12.29027795791626, 8.1415114402771, 6.129252195358276
25000: 32.34258818626404, 23.32529616355896, 18.124294996261597
50000: 63.35693168640137, 40.77235984802246, 30.406764268875122
```

using `workbook = Workbook(file_path_out, {'constant_memory': True})` will improve the runtimes even more (but not really much: 1s faster for 25k rows=

Comment: Is there any significant improvement in `export_excel` if you use xlsxwriter `worksheet.write_column()` instead of `df.iterrows()` and `worksheet.write_row()`?

Comment: Nope. And now, i am in holidays

Answer (score 1):

According to [`pandas.DataFrame.to_excel` docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html) `engine` value might be either `openpyxl` or `xlsxwriter`, as you use latter one I suggest to test `engine='openpyxl'` vs `engine='xlsxwriter'`.

Comment: I've updated the question with `openpyxl` results.