# Faster way to write multiple data frames to excel

Tags: python, pandas, excel

I'm reading a csv file which contains around 1 million rows and 177 columns using pandas and then I wish to write (append) those chunks into a single xlsx file, basically converting the csv file to xlsx format using the below code.

```
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl
import timeit
import xlsxwriter
import os
import numpy as np

def process_csv_files(csv_file_path, excel_base_path, chunk_size):
    try:
        print(f'csv_file_path : {csv_file_path}')
        print(f'excel_base_path : {excel_base_path}')
        print(f'chunk_size : {chunk_size}')
        base_file_name, _ = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(csv_file_path))
        excel_file_path = f'{base_file_name}.xlsx'
        excel_file_path = os.path.join(excel_base_path, excel_file_path)
        counter = 1
        if os.path.getsize(csv_file_path) > 0 :                                
            
            with pd.ExcelWriter(excel_file_path, engine='xlsxwriter') as writer:
                for i, chunk in enumerate(pd.read_csv(csv_file_path, chunksize=chunk_size, keep_default_na=False, na_filter=False, dtype=str)):
                    start_time = timeit.default_timer()                    
                    chunk.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet', index=False, startrow=i * chunk_size, header=False)
                    elapsed_time = timeit.default_timer() - start_time
                    print(f'writing chunk completed in {elapsed_time} seconds for chunk number : {counter} ')
                    counter += 1
                print(f'Successfully converted file : {csv_file_path}')
    except Exception as e:
        print('Error encountered in process_csv_files ' + str(e))

try:
    start_time_main = timeit.default_timer()
    output_base_path = 'output_directory_path'
    csv_file_path = '/input_directory_path/example.csv'
    chunk_size = 10000      
    process_csv_files(csv_file_path, output_base_path, chunk_size)
    elapsed_time = timeit.default_timer() - start_time_main
    print(f'Successfully converted the job in : {elapsed_time} seconds.')     
    
except Exception as e:
    print('Error encountered in csv_to_excel_convertor ' + str(e))
```

Things tried so far:

- Find the optimal chunk size by varying the number (10,000 is the
  optimal number).
- Tried multiple xlsx format writer engines (xlsx    writer works the
  best for me).
- Tried to read columns with appropriate dtype (it    definitely helps
  in reducing the memory usage but the time    taken    for writing
  still remains the same).

Followed few similar asked [question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25863381/python-fastest-way-to-write-pandas-dataframe-to-excel-on-multiple-sheets) [question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73319597/pandas-df-to-excel-is-way-to-slow-is-there-anyway-to-speed-it-up) but they are not that helpful.

Code works but it takes around 13 seconds to process (read & write) a single chunk (10,000 rows * 177 columns), is there a way to **improve/make this work faster**.?

Comment: Is pandas required? I would stream read rows using the csv package and write using openpyxl and wite-only mode.

Comment: @JonSG I did try that but surprisingly for me the solution that is pasted above gave better results, anything else that I can try on?

Comment: I noticed that [pandas 2.2.0](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/whatsnew/v2.2.0.html#) supports the fast Rust calamite library, but that seems to be only for *reading* Excel files.

Comment: I haven't found a faster way than what you have despite trying - to_excel is just slow. You could consider something totally different and use win32 to programmatically open the csv in Excel then save_as xlsx.

Comment: I haven't personally used polars, but you could give it a try [pandas vs polars](https://www.shipyardapp.com/blog/pandas-vs-polars/)